# Azure purge script from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-cdn

We are deploying web app to Azure cdn, but every time we need to wait pretty much time before app is updated. So we found out that there is a 'purge' button, which seems to work. After purge we have to wait like 5 min.

Now we want to run this every time app is released so we added a task to vsts with following script :

```
az cdn endpoint purge --resource-group $1 --profile-name $3 --name $4 --content-paths /*
```

with arguments: `$(ResourceGroup) $(StorageAccountName) $(ProfileName) $(EndpointName)`

but this does not work every time, seems like sometimes it works and after 5 min app is updated but sometimes we have to wait like 30 min.

Comment: Are you using Verizon or Akamai or Microsoft Standard CDN?

Comment: @msrini-MSIT Standard Microsoft

Comment: Does the operation takes 30 mins to complete? Or the operation is completed but it doesn't work for 30 mins?

Comment: @msrini-MSIT definitely second option, release is done, purge took from 2 up to 6 minutes and then sometimes, even after one hour the app is not updated, and we have to press purge on azure manually.

Comment: @kosnkov Did you ever work this out?  Which version of the CDN are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the --no-wait parameter to avoid waiting for the operation to finish.

```
az cdn endpoint purge --resource-group $1 --profile-name $3 --name $4 --no-wait --content-paths /*
```

> --no-wait
>
> Do not wait for the long-running operation to finish.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cdn/endpoint?view=azure-cli-latest#optional-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Provide content paths in "" or ''

`az cdn endpoint purge --resource-group $1 --profile-name $3 --name $4 --no-wait --content-paths "/*"`

where provide values for $1 $3 $4 as -

```
$1 => name of resource group
$3 => CDN profile name (exclude the suffix **.azureedge.net**)
$4 => name of the endpoint
```